# Namespace conflict. Own spl_autoload_register for different directories

Tags: php

I create own wordpress starter kit for plugins and themes.

I want use php namespaces in my projects (wp plugins and themes).

I set up `spl_autoload_register` function:

[image]
[image]

All is well. Until I create 2 projects based on my starter-kit. In this case, I get an error `Cannot redeclare class ...`.

All plugins and themes are in separate directories. And in each such folder there is my starter kit with `spl_autoload_register` function.

My structure:

[image]

**How do I avoid name conflicts?**
**And what can happen if someone else registers a function `spl_autoload_register`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I avoid name conflicts?

Use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

> what can happen if someone else registers a function `spl_autoload_register`?

When it needs to use a class that is not declared, the interpreter invokes the autoload functions registered using [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) one by one in the order they were registered until the class becomes available.

Comment: When I use my starter kit I just do `git clone` in my new plugin directory. Next, I need to change the config.php file. And I can start working on a new plugin. If I need to use different namespaces for different plugins, then I will have to change all namespaces in each new plugin. Right? If so, it's not convenient.  Maybe I'm not right about the task?

Comment: You have the same problem with or without namespaces. What a namespace provides is, more or less, longer names for objects. You cannot have two functions with the same name in the project (or classes or constants). But, you can have two functions that have the same name but in different namespaces. Otherwise, if they use the same names for functions, how do you expect PHP (and WP) tells one of your plugins apart from the others?

Comment: Then I see only one solution. This makes my starter kit as a separate plugin. The other plugins make dependent on this plugin. Then I can use classes from the starter kit in all plugins. And classes in the plugins will have unique namespaces. But it will still not be as convenient as I wanted :)

Comment: If you don't manually include files and the autoloader callback you register uses a consistent rule, there is no reason to get the "Cannot redeclare class ..." error message. Each class is uniquely identified by its fully-qualified name (name prefixed by the namespace) and if a class was already loaded then the autoloader is not invoked. The only way it can happen is when the autoloader callback loads additional classes (or a different class) than the one that it is asked to load. The extra class(es) it loads might already exist and this causes the error.